# string for image won't print correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, web

Ok I have an array `myIconPath[]` of images `"img/myIcons/imgIcon_12.png"` <-- one example

I have some javascript that writes that writes a list item for each icon in the array

```
document.write('<li><a href="' + "test2.jsp" + 
               '" title="' + myTitleName + 
               '"><img src="'  + myIconPath[i] + 
               '" alt="' + myAltName + '"  /></a></li>');
```

This works beautifully.

But I want to get rid of the `img/myIcons` extension so that I can just load `"imgIcon_1.png"`

When I try that very thing, replacing

```
<img src="'  + myIconPath + '"...
```

with

```
<img src="' + 'img/myIcons/' + actImageArray[i] + '"...
```

it only loads the first icon. the rest are blank. I'm sure there's so syntactical mistake in here. What could it possibly be though?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Use String#replace to replace the path with a blank string and then trim it.

```
var imgSrc = myIconPath[i].replace('img/myIcons/', '').trim();

document.write('<li><a href="' + "test2.jsp" + 
               '" title="' + myTitleName + 
               '"><img src="'  + imgSrc + 
               '" alt="' + myAltName + '"  /></a></li>');
```

Comment: maybe I'm using it wrong. but I just put the `myIconPath[i].replace('img/myIcons/', '').trim()` line in instead of saving it to a `var`.

Comment: Is this fixed? @user3202810.